# Bulk Insert error in SQL Server stored procedure : Can not open the file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, nas

One of our stored procedures uses bulk insert statement to load data in the NAS (Network Attached Storage). This stored procedure is executed by a SQL Server Agent job. The owner of the job (`DEV\f29`) has full control over the NAS.

Other SQL jobs copying files from one folder to another in the NAS succeed. However, the Bulk Insert fails with the error:

> Can not open the file (\FS\abc\abc.txt)"

We are using Windows authentication.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be that file is opened by any other process and Is locked, you can check that using [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Comment: `\FS\abc\abc.txt` seems to be missing the leading double-backslash that makes it a UNC path. Shouldn't it be `\\FS\abc\abc.txt`?

Comment: Thank you, eshirvana and AlwaysLearning! I will double check if it is due to file being locked by other processes. BTW- it is double-backslash in the code (\\FS\abc\abc.txt).